# console returning Unexpected token ')' while everything syntaxed perfectly in document.contains property

Tags: javascript

hello i have syntaxed perfectly the code (as i think)
but console.log still returning

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

```
function checker() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.task-content').forEach( a => {
    if (a.classList.contains("delete")) {
      console.log('yes');

    } else {
      console.log('no');
  });
}
checker();
```

the console referring to the line in the end of else  the for each closing tag ')'
, as i want to check if 'a variable' contains class of delete

Comment: `delete` is a reserved javascript keyword, hence the `)` following was not expected by the javascript engine. You're probably looking for `a.classList.contains('delete')`

Comment: And `querySelectorAll` returns an array, not an element.

Comment: still same probloem kindly help

Comment: Track your `(`s and `{` where is `forEach(` closing? you have closed it right after you closed `else` but... you did not close the lambda I think. Try changing `});` to `}});`. A good IDE would help with this

Answer (score 2):

The error message is kind of misleading. You are using `delete` as an identifier (variable name), but `delete` is a reserved word and can't be used as such.

Also, `querySelectorAll` returns an array, not an element, so you need to use `querySelector` or iterate over the array (like I did here).

Maybe you meant:

```js
function checker() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.task-content').forEach( a => {
    if (a.classList.contains("delete")) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
  });
}
checker();
```

```html
<a class="task-content">foo</a>
<a class="task-content delete">bar</a>
```

Comment: i want to use delete as a class name not variable

Comment: is it by adding " " ?

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap it in quotes because it's a string.

Comment: still the same probloem

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'   ,,,, code is not working

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: yes i tried yours

Comment: also the class name is generated on js not html is that probloem

Comment: This answer doesn't close the *else*-statement with a `}` if you add that it works.

Comment: no its not working  i checked everything

Comment: @3limin4t0r You're right, it's now fixed